# Can't use my own discontinuous coefficient within NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, discontinuity

I want to evaluate the pendulum's motion with changing equilibrium state given by `eqilValue[t]`:

```
tauArr = {50, 100, 150, 200, 250}; (* points of changing, there may be a lot of them *)
(* that's why i need a function *)
eqilValue[t_] := (If[0 <= t < tauArr[[1]], eV = 0]; 
  If[t >= tauArr[[Length[tauArr]]], eV = -5];
  For[j = 1, j <= (Length[tauArr] - 1), j++, 
   {If[tauArr[[j]] <= t < tauArr[[j + 1]], eV = j]}];
  Return[eV]
);(* equilibrium states, for example *)

gamma = 0.1;
kappa = 0.1;

sol = First[
     f /. NDSolve[{f''[t] + gamma*f'[t] + kappa*(f[t] - eqilValue[t]) == 0,
       f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0}, f, {t, 0, 300}]];
Plot[eqilValue[t], {t, 0, 400}]
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 300}, PlotRange -> All]
```

This code throws an error when launched first time, otherwise shows a wrong behavior, just like there is the only final state:

```
(*NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`. >>

 ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{0.01 (Times[<<2>>]+f[<<1>>])+0.1 (f^\[Prime])[t]+(f^          \[Prime]\[Prime])[t]==0,f[0]==0,(f^\[Prime])[0]==0},f,{t,0,300}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
*)
```

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to set up differential equations with discontinuities in the coefficients?

Comment: Define `eqilValue` this way: `eqilValue[t_?NumericQ] := (...)`.  The need for and use of `?NumericQ` is explained in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) to the "Pitfalls" question and its links.

Comment: FWIW, you might be interested in [Alternatives to procedural loops](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).  *Mathematica* has tools built in to support Fortran/C/Java type programming, such as `For`, which lets folks transition more easily.  But they don't work as well with the rest of *M* as other tools.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question to include the part about handling discontinuous function.  If you don't like it, feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. I think belisarius's answer shows there is an interesting aspect to the problem that the edited question now reflects.  It also a good question for exhibiting some new abilities of `DSolve`.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's better to cope with discontinuous functions in `NDSolse[]` by using  `WhenEvent[]` and `DiscreteVariables ->`. In your case:

```
tauArr = {50, 100, 150, 200, 250};
whens = WhenEvent @@@ MapIndexed[{t == #1, ep[t] -> If[#2 == {5}, -5, #2[[1]]]} &, tauArr]
sol = NDSolve[{f''[t] + gamma*f'[t] + kappa*(f[t] - ep[t]) == 0, 
              whens, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, ep[0] == 0}, f, {t, 0, 300}, 
              DiscreteVariables -> {ep}]
Plot[f[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 300}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a nice answer to a better question.  I think I'll edit the question to match.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

`NDSolve` and now, in V10, `DSolve`, too, can handle differential equations with discontinuous coefficients.  The coefficients have to be in terms of functions that will be recognized as discontinuous.  Procedural programs such as in the definition of `eqilValue` above will not be recongnized and will be treated as numerical black boxes.  `Piecewise` will be recognized and both `NDSolve` and `DSolve` analyze the function and attempt to determine where the discontinuities occur.  One thing that is a little different with `DSolve` is that one has to ((always?) specify a finite interval.  `DSolve` will construct a piecewise solution that is valid over the interval.

We can use either `NDSolve` or `DSolve`. I'll show `DSolve`.  It is new and can actually give an "exact" solution -- exact, except for the approximate parameters `gamma` and `kappa`.

```
eqVal = Piecewise[
  MapIndexed[{First[#2] - 1, t < #1} &, tauArr],
  -5];

sol = DSolve[{f''[t] + gamma*f'[t] + kappa*(f[t] - eqVal) == 0, f[0] == 0, 
  f'[0] == 0}, f, {t, 0, 300}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[f[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 300}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Remarks: (1) If we replace `DSolve` by `NDSolve` above, we will of course get an interpolating function that closely approximates the exact solution.  I'm not sure of the differences in how `NDSolve` processes the piecewise coefficient and how it processes the `WhenEvent` method of [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius).  Usually, `NDSolve` uses root-finding algorithms to locate events, but for equations of the form `t == t0`, root-finding and solving exactly are pretty much the same thing.  They certainly are in this case where the `t0` are integers.  In any case, there's not a great difference in the two methods.

(2) The `eqilValue` function had a regular pattern that facilitated the construction of the `Piecewise` expression (and `WhenEvent` expressions).  For an irregular pattern, one can simply construct them by hand.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about DSolve new juggles (Still on 9 here)

Comment: @belisarius Thanks.  DSolve can also do delay differential equations (over a finite interval) in the same way (piecewise solution).